# Swift: Autoplay and auto fullScreen for youtube video

Tags: ios, swift, video, youtube

I have to embed youtube videos in my swift application. The video have to be played automatically after a button click and in the fullScreen mode. I have searched a lot and I have found that many ways exists to embed youtube videos but not all of them support the autoplay and the auto fullScreen. 
I have tested this code but the video is not autoplayed and it’s not automatically showed in fullScreen mode:

```
 let webView:UIWebView = UIWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height))
        self.view.addSubview(webView)

        webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
        let myVideo = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/N-GNV7jhKV4"

        let myHTML = "<iframe width=\"\(webView.frame.size.width)\" height=\"\(webView.frame.size.height)\" src=\"\(myVideo)?autoplay=1\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen=1></iframe>"

        webView.loadHTMLString(myHTML, baseURL: nil)
        webView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = false
```

Can someone please tell me what is the best way to satisfy all the conditions cited above (autoplay and auto full screen) between my code, the  [YouTube-Player-iOS-Helper](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper) and [Swift-YouTube-Player](https://github.com/gilesvangruisen/Swift-YouTube-Player) or if someone have other suggestions.